# Internal homs in a locale seems to be symmetric?

Tags: category-theory, cartesian-closed-categories, locales

TL;DR: just read the last sentence of the question.

I'm watching a video series on intro level topos theory. It introduces sheaves on a locale as part of the motivation. It claims the following fact:

> A locale, viewed as a category (with relation ≤ as morphism), is cartesian closed.

The construction is given explicitly:

$$
(v ⇒ w) := \bigvee_{u ∧ v ≤ w} u
$$

It is described as the "largest open set whose intersection with $v$ is ≤ $w$".

I tried to use my intuition on topological spaces to understand this construction: consider the discrete topology, and the largest such open set is just the union of the following:

1. $v ∧ w$, and
2. the complement of $v ∨ w$.

This really seems to be symmetric, say, exchanging $v$ and $w$ really gives the same set, but it may also not be the case because I only considered the discrete topology. So here's my question:

Consider the internal hom $v ⇒ w$ in a locale viewed as a category. Is it equal to $w ⇒ v$?

Comment: I don't get why "the complement of $v\lor w$. Don't you mean "the complement of $v$"? Imagine for instance that $v$ and $w$ are disjoint. Then the set we are looking for is the complement of $v$, not of $v\lor w$.

Comment: @CaptainLama oh no! I made a mistake! What should I do?

Comment: @ice1000: If Captain Lama's answer allowed you to identify the source of your mistake/confusion, you can ask them to write up their comment as an answer, and if they do, you should then accept it.

Comment: In the case of a discrete topological space, $(v \Rightarrow w) = (v^c \cup w)$ where $v^c$ is the complement of $v$.  For a more general topological space, $(v \Rightarrow w) = \operatorname{int}(v^c \cup w)$.

Comment: In fact, it turns out that in any Heyting algebra, if $(v \Rightarrow w) = (w \Rightarrow v)$, then $v = w$.  This ended up being a nice little exercise.

Comment: @CaptainLama hi! Can you write me an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that, as was pointed out in the comments, you made a little mistake which explains your confusion: the definition of $(v⇒ w)$ implies that it is the union of $v\land w$ and the complement of $v$, rather than the complement of $v\lor w$.

For instance, if $v$ and $w$ are disjoint, then $(v⇒ w)$ is just $\overline{v}$ (this is clearly the largest open whose intersection with $v$ is $\leqslant w$).